# Px, Pn when Debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When debugging C++ in Visual Studio, if you add a watch onto an object you see 'px' and 'pn' as its immediate children.

I have always read 'px' to mean the pointer to the actual object, but I'm curious what these 'px', 'pn' and 'pi' codes are actually short for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose what you see is content of `boost::shared_ptr` instance that indeed contains `px` and `pn` members:

```
element_type * px;                 // contained pointer
boost::detail::shared_count pn;    // reference counter
```

So, these are not some kind of magic debugger variables but real class fields and you won't see them in regular objects.

Comment: Yes, this was a Boost shared ptr.